# Comportamento anômalo do Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

Uso o `Google Analytics` em meu site porem ele tem um comportamento anômalo:

- Quando abro 2 até infinitas páginas do meu site em um unico navegador é 
  computado como um unico usuário ativo.
- Quando abro 2 até infinitas páginas do meu site em 2 navegadores são 
  computados como 2 usuários ativos.
- Quando fecho as páginas não é atualizado o numero de usuários ativos no site.
- Quando deixo as abas abertas porem sem qualquer atualização ou redirecionamento 
  o número de usuarios onlines é atualizado a 0.

Estou usando um código do google analytics assincrono e otimizado (O coloquei 
em um arquivo .js externo (que contem outras funções javascript, porem não há 
interfrencia entre variaveis)):

```
var _gaq = [['_setAccount', 'UA-63633330-1'], ['_trackPageview']];
(function(d, t){
    var g = d.createElement(t),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
}(document, 'script'));
```

Qual a razão para este comportamento anômalo ou este é o comportamento adequado?

Link do site que disponibilizou a versão otimizada do Google Analytics: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet

Comment: Posso dar mais detalhes caso necessário. é só pedir nos comentários =D

Comment: Ricardo eu só não entendi qual dos comportamentos é anômalo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ao meu ver todos os três, ou interpretei errado e estes são os corpotamentos normais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podemos dizer que **sim**, todos me parecem "corretos" com a lógica do funcionamento da maioria dos *"contadores online"*, espero que isto lhe ajude:

> **Q:** Quando abro 2 até infinitas páginas do meu site em um único navegador é computado como um único usuário ativo.

- **R:** Sim são considerados único, pois é necessários para fazer a métrica e geralmente usado para definir o passo-a-passo do cliente, por exemplo em um site de compras se o usuário abrir várias janelas ou abas será necessário verificar por onde ele passou até atingir o **goal** (neste exemplo seria concluir a compra)

> **Q:** Quando abro 2 até infinitas páginas do meu site em 2 navegadores são computados como 2 usuários ativos.

- **R:** Cada navegador tem um [*User-Agent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) (identificação das tecnologias o qual o usuário está usando para navegar) diferente e também não usam a mesma sessão/cookies, portanto não é possível determinar que são usuário diferentes. Eles poderiam até usar o IP, mas se dois computadores usarem a mesma REDE o IP será igual e isto causaria conflitos e dados irreais (misturados).

> **Q:** Quando fecho as páginas não é atualizado o numero de usuários ativos no site.

- **R:** O navegador tem um evento javascript chamado [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), porém ele só funciona bem no *front-end*, se usa-lo para fazer uma requisição ajax por exemplo, ao momento que fechar o navegador ele vai chamar o ajax, mas não vai ter tempo de concluir a entrega do pedido no servidor, as vezes consegue, mas não é garantido. Eles poderiam usa-lo para auxiliar, mas ao invés disto eles utilizam um tempo aproximado de um minuto para verificar as atividades do usuário, se o usuário fechou o navegador, após um minuto ele é removido da "quantidade de usuários online" e este é o processo mais garantido de funcionar hoje em dia.

> **Q:** Quando deixo as abas abertas porem sem qualquer atualização ou redirecionamento o número de usuários onlines é atualizado a 0.

- **R:** É a mesma situação do anterior, se o usuário está inativo no site mesmo que com abas abertas, o contador deve desconsiderar depois de um minuto (~aproximado) o usuário, pois o que importa é a atividade dentro do site, se o usário está em outra aba não tem porque contabilizar ele. No momento que ele executar uma atividade o contador atualiza.

### Conclusão

Navegadores podem falhar, pode haver queda de energia, por isto o sistema de "um minuto" (~aproximado) é o melhor para verificar se o usuário está ativo se comparado ao evento [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload). Note que este "método" não é só no google, mas outros sistemas iguais e até mais simples usam o mesmo procedimento (como aqueles chats online de suporte ao visitante)

Comment: Eu estou aprendendo SEO agora então ainda não tinha certeza se estes comportamentos estavam corretos ou não então decidi conferir, agora sei que estão corretos, obrigado.

Comment: GuilhermeNascimento um ponto que esqueci de frisar é que o código do *Google Analytics* está em um arquivo externo .js e que ele foi otimizado (mas pelos comentários esta otimização não causou danos) estes fatores podem influenciar em algo?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Optimizado você quer dizer que você modificou como ele é chamado ou você recriou o código? Geralmente o código dele é chamado com `document.createElement` que include um `.js` em tempo de execução. Acredito que não ocorra problema algum adicionar dentro de um .js no seu servidor, desde que a chamada ocorra no ponto do que seria equivalente ao $.ready do jquery.

Comment: GuilhermeNascimento esta otimização foi encontrada neste site: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet o código foi reduzido em 50% (e aparentemente funciona) e copiei o código e colei no arquivo .js fora de qualquer função.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique sim esta optimização parece funcionar mesmo :) Obrigado por compartilhar.

Comment: GuilhermeNascimento, de nada, mas o que eu queria saber mesmo é se colocar este código direto no .js externo (fora de qualquer função) tem algum risco ou contra indicação?

Comment: Então @RicardoHenrique pode sim colocar dentro de um .js, mas o tempo da chamada dele acredito que tenha que ser no mesmo do `$.ready`, ou seja quando o `document` estiver pronto (diferente do onlonad que todos resources tem que estar prontos), pois até aonde me lembro sempre adicionamos o `ga` antes do `</body>` e isto seria equivalente ao `.ready` do jquery. Faz um tempo que não trabalho com o GA, mas irei ver assim que voltar da minhas mini-férias :) - na segunda