# Efetuar Logout com Evento Javascript quando fechar a janela

Tags: javascript

#### Situação

Tenho um sistema no qual preciso que o usuário seja deslogado quando fechar o navegador.

#### Code

desta maneira consegui pegar o fechamento do navegador, ou melhor dizer a 'saída' da pagina para uma nova ( ou não em caso de fechamento de navegador ). Porém está me barrando na confirmação.

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compatable

    myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
      var confirm = window.confirm('Deseja fazer logout?');
      if(confirm){
        logout();
      }
    });

    function logout (){
      console.log('Logout');
    }
```

#### Erro

> Blocked confirm('Deseja fazer logout?') during beforeunload

Alguem teria outra maneira de efeutar essa funcionalidade?

Comment: O que queres dizer com `Porém está me barrando na confirmação`?

Comment: Seria que no metodo que chamo `window.confirm()` ele bloqueia por estar no `beforeunload`. Confirmação seria a resposta do usuário se quer ou não efetuar o logout, quero tratar e abaixo tomar a decisão de ir para meu logoff ou continuar na pagina.

Comment: você usa o que para manter o usuario conectado no sistema? sessões ?

Comment: é por Cookies uso TOKEN. Mas o meu problema em sí não é deslogar e sim a função ali dentro. =D

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 2):

O `window.confirm` não irá funcionar pois a estrutura do `onbeforeunload` já possui um `return` para a tela de confirmação, acredito que o correto seria isto:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Gostaria mesmo de sair?";
};
```

Porém note que não será possível disparar eventos se clicar em "Ok", pois a janela já terá fechado, no momento que a janela ou aba se fecha a sua *instancia* é destruída e por este motivo não é mais possivel enviar eventos, pois ela já não "existe".

Então se você quer criar um evento que deslogue o usuário do seu sistema (supondo que esteja usando `php`, `.net`, `jsf`, etc) será necessário criar um "timer" para expirar o usuário, um bom tempo seria "2 mintuos", note que o [Google Analytics](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68414/comportamento-an%C3%B4malo-do-google-analytics) utiliza uma técnica semelhante ao que mencionei.

No caso do autor, está usando *Ruby On Rails*, pode tentar isto (conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424354/1518921)):

[Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) pode fazer isto por padrão. Sugiro você migrar o seu sistema de autenticação (pode levar algum tempo dependendo do quanto o seu sistema é customizado).

Existem este exemplo também http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example

Comment: Entendo. nao tem uma maneira então só de pegar o `ok`  que apertar e verificar se foi true ou false ? e ai sim criar algo faça o logout entao.

Comment: entendi, é feito em Ruby. =D

Comment: @ralfting veja se consegue aplicar está logica ao RoR http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71023/3635

Comment: A blz, vou testar isso sim. Ver oque consigo fazer e dou um feedback aqui.. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @ralfting Só não lhe auxilio com o ROR pois o meu conhecimento nisto é limitado e a sua pergunta aqui é voltado ao problema `Blocked confirm('Deseja fazer logout?') during beforeunload`, mas aguardo seu feedback

Comment: Ta beleza realmente iria preferir tratar isso no html pois será um evento disparado pelo usuário.

Comment: @ralfting para facilitar editei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo em ROR, espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado! irei ver.