# Verificar se o usuário fechou o navegador

Tags: php, navegador-de-internet, session

Haveria maneira de eu saber quando um usuário fecha o navegador e, antes de fechar, gravar no banco que sua sessão está inativa? Ou, como posso fazer algum programa externo que monitore se a pessoa está com o navegador aberto, e quando não obtiver resposta, considera que fechou o navegador?

Tenho uma aplicação que permite que haja no máximo três usuários logados com a mesma conta. No momento em que o usuário loga, guardo no banco seu id de usuário e a hora e data em que logou, bem como uma flag 'ativo' indicando que ele está logado. Se a pessoa tentar um quarto login, verifico pelo banco que já há três autenticações para aquele usuário e barro a quarta.

Se ele faz logout, gravo essa informação no banco e permito que ele faça login mais uma vez, até o limite de três logins. Sei quando o usuário faz logout, mas não sei quando ele fecha o navegador.

Comment: Imagine que eu estou acessando o seu site quando falta luz: obviamente é impossível detectar que eu “fechei” o navegador. O seu objetivo é promover segurança do usuário (e.g. se tiver um monte de gente acessando a mesma conta ao mesmo tempo tem algo estranho acontecendo), ou o objetivo é promover a segurança do seu serviço (e.g. não deixar 30 pessoas compartilharem a mesma conta do NetFlix/Spotify/etc.)?

Comment: por javascript existe metodo onclose que verifica se o usuario fechou o navegador depois por ajax manda um programa server-side gravar.

Comment: Na verdade tem como você fazer meio que uma verificação, não acredito que e uma gambiarra... você verifica se o usuário esta muito tempo inativo, se estiver + que um certo tempo que você estipula pra que um usuário fique inativo, então você da um meta refresh na pagina e manda pro servidor pra deslogar essa conta

Comment: Por exemplo: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600; url=suapropriapagina.php?action=deslogar">`

Comment: Boa noite Leo, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, **se não por favor** comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em uma resposta curta **Não é possível** enviar uma requisição, pois no momento que a janela do navegador é fechada a *instancia* dela é destruída e não tem como enviar uma requisição a tempo para o back-end.

A melhor maneira, como instrui nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70983/3635) é criar um "timer" para a sessão do usuário e este acredito se o melhor método, visando que o [Google Analytics](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68414/3635) usa uma técnica semelhante.

Vamos supor que você tem uma tabela no banco de usuários

```
id | login | senha | nome | lastactive
-----------------------------------------------
1  | test  | test  | João | 2015-06-24 01:00:23
-----------------------------------------------
2  | maria | maria | Maria| 2015-06-24 01:00:33
```

Você terá que usar um tempo minimo de atividade na camada do PHP para definir se o "usuário está online".

A cada requisição do usuário `test` (supondo que esteja logado co), deve-se executar um `update` na tabela para o `id` dele:

```
 UPDATE usuarios SET lastactive=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id=1
```

Para exibição deste usuário aos demais usuário (por exemplo se for um chat) o PHP deveria ser algo como:

```
define('REQUEST_TIME', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
define('TIME_ONLINE', 120);//120 = 2 minutos

function isOnline($timer) {
    return REQUEST_TIME - strtotime($timer) > TIME_ONLINE;
}

$query = 'SELECT nome, lastactive WHERE 1 ORDER by nome';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'Usuário ', $row['nome'], ' está ',
             (isOnline($row['lastactive']) ? 'online' : 'offline'), '<br>';
    }

    $result->free();
}
```

Neste exemplo, se o usuário estiver sem realizar uma atividade a mais de 2 minutos, ele é considerado "offline" para os demais usuários ou qualquer outra ação, basta usar a função `isOnline`, se for `TRUE` pode executar um comando no usuário, pois ele está `online`, se for `FALSE` ele está "offline", portanto você pode ignorar ou vice-versa, vai depender do que você quer fazer com os usuários online/offline.

Answer (score 1):

Atualmente eu não achei nenhuma forma elegante de verificar quando o usuário fecha o navegador para abrir a possibilidade de mais uma conexão, por isto eu utilizo outra metodologia para resolução deste problema, vejamos.

**1° Logar**

quando a pessoa logar no sistema você valida  fazendo um `select` do usuário e senha e se positivo cria uma sessão para ele permanecer logado certo? você pode criar dois campos idnet e dataAcesso no Banco de dados e atualiza-lo  com  uma chave e a data atual.
O (idnet - chave)  é para identificar  qual sessão você esta usando você pode criar assim:

```
function geraidnet() {
   $idnet = rand();
   $idnet = mb_strtoupper(md5($idnet));
   $_SESSION['IDNET'] = $idnet;
   return $idnet;
}

$idnet = geraidnet();
```

A dataAcesso e para verificar o tempo que a pessoa esta ociosa.
Voce pode zerar o idnet e dataAcesso quando a pessoa ficar ociosa, exemplo por 5 minutos:

```
 $sql = 'UPDATE USUARIOS' . "\n" .
        '   SET DATA_ACESSO = NULL ,' . "\n" .
        '       IDNET = NULL' . "\n" .
        ' WHERE DATA_ACESSO menorQ (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 0.00347)';
```

Todos os usuarios que ficaram 5 minutos ociosos no sistema terão seus idnet e dataAcesso zerados agora você pode fazer um select para verificar quantos usuarios estão logados.

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(0) AS QUANT_UL' . "\n" .
        '  FROM USUARIOS' . "\n" .
        ' WHERE DATA_ACESSO IS NOT NULL';

if (($result = $db->Execute($sql)) == false):
   throw new Exception($db->ErrorMsg());
endif;

if ($result->fields['QUANT_UL'] menorQ 10): // só pode haver ate 10 conexões
   $sql = 'UPDATE USUARIOS' . "\n" .
           '   SET DATA_ACESSO = \'' . $data_acesso . '\',' . "\n" .
           '       IDNET       = \'' . $idnet . '\'' . "\n" .
           ' WHERE id      = ' . $idusuario;
else:
   throw new Exception('O número máximo de conexões foi atingido!');
endif;
```

Tudo que você precisa fazer agora e atualizar a dataAcesso do usuario quando o mesmo realizar alguma operação no seu sistema.