# Atualizar banco de dados quando usuario desconectar ao fechar browser

Tags: php

Estou tentando atualizar o banco de dados com a rotina abaixo informando que o CPF nao esta mais logado, ou seja, substituir no banco de dados a letra "S" por "N", mas nao esta funcionando.

```
   <?php
   session_start();

// Desconecta usuario
   include ('Conexao.php');
   $cpef= $_SESSION['Usuario'];
   $query = "UPDATE funcionarios SET Logado = 'N' WHERE cpef = '$cpef'";
   mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

   unset($_SESSION['Usuario']);
   unset($_SESSION['Permissao']);

   header("Location: index.php");
   exit();
```

?>

Comment: Boas-vindas. Como expliquei nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80707/3635, apenas Beacon API vai tentar entregar um requisição, mesmo após o unload da página, então você pode combinar Beacon API com beforeunload. Entretanto outros tipos de situações, como fechamento arbitrário, por queda de energia, ou falha nos softwares do usuário, não irão disparar eventos no JavaScript.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é criar um timeout no back-end, se o usuário não terminou a ação dentro do tempo estipulado, considerando horaatual > horainicio + tempo_limite, você pode considerar como deslogado, sem precisar alterar nada no banco, aqui forneci uma solução por tempo que resolve o caso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71023/3635

Comment: Conversa movida para o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145559/discussion-on-question-by-giuliano-romanholo-atualizar-banco-de-dados-quando-usu)