# Destruir session ao sair da página

Tags: php, javascript, session

Possuo um sistema para cadastro de orçamentos e preciso que, quando a pessoa fechar a página, antes, exiba uma mensagem de confirmação, se realmente deseja sair da página. Se ela confirmar, destruir a sessão.

Session que preciso:

```
$_SESSION['produtos']
```

Comment: Por que não define um `lifetime` específico para o Cookie. Se a pessoa fechar o navegador, já fecha a sessão.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A identificação da sessão do usuário se dá por um *cookie* - por padrão, o nome do *cookie* é `PHPSESSID`. Se o usuário perder o *cookie*, ele perderá a sessão, simples assim.

Assim, para que a sessão se mantenha viva apenas enquanto o usuário possuir o navegador aberto, basta você configurar para que o *cookie* sobreviva enquanto o usuário manter o navegador aberto.

Em tempo de execução, você pode configurar isso com a função `session_set_cookie_params`, ou pode alterar seu `php.ini` de acordo:

```
void session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]] )
```

O primeiro parâmetro define o tempo de vida do *cookie* da sessão, em segundos. Se informado o valor 0, que é o padrão, o *cookie* expirará quando o navegador for fechado.

Inclusive, opções como "Lembrar-me" durante o *login* costumam apenas definir um tempo diferente de 0 para o tempo de vida do *cookie*, assim ele será persistido no navegador mesmo quando este for fechado.

---

Quanto à mensagem de confirmação para fechar a página, você deve fazer isso com JavaScript, sem relação alguma com o PHP. Algo como, por exemplo, ouvir o evento `unload` da janela:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Gostaria mesmo de sair?";
};
```

<sup>[Créditos ao Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70994/5878)</sup>

> Talvez não seja exatamente isso, pois tentei reproduzir e não consegui. Buscarei mais detalhes, mas se alguém souber, só avisar que já edito.

Comment: Melhor opção. Não tem porque complicar tanto isso. +1

Comment: `unload` deveria ser trocado por beforeunload, creio eu, e confirm não deve ser necessário.

Comment: Só um detalhe, onbeforeunload não é para detectar fechamentos, na verdade eu pessoalmente considero que qualquer cenário pensando em usar para coisa semelhante um baita problema, já que na verdade ele detecta descarregamentos e não fechamentos, relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256171/3635