# Jquery beforeunload é chamado quando clico em link

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Quero executar uma função somente quando o usuário fechar o navegador, porém quando clico em um link o evento é acionado mesmo assim.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/phpPerfil/brownserClosed.php"
    });
});
```

Como chamar a função somente quando o usuário fechar o navegador?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beforeunload` não é usado para detectar quando as abas fecham ou janelas fecham é usado para detectar o "descarregamento" da página, ou seja este evento é disparado também quando você clicar em um link que vai pra outra página, pois a página atual será descarregada para poder carregar a nova.

**Importante:** Não tem como detectar a diferença de *"maneira confiável"* se está fechando ou paginando no evento `beforeunload`.

O que você pode fazer é usar páginação com Ajax e o `history.pushState` para mudar a URL, ao invés de paginações reais, no entanto o uso de `beforeunload` com ajax também é problemático quando fechamos abas e janelas, leia a seguir.

### Porque não é recomendado usar beforeunload

Note uma coisa **muito importante**, não recomendo usar `beforeunload` pra detectar que a página fechou, pois isto não pode ser garantido, pelos seguintes problemas que a requisição ajax não poderá ser entregue pro servidor:

- Ao fechar uma aba ou janela todas requisições ajax são canceladas
- Pode ocorrer do navegador congelar ou fechar por causa de um erro (crash), então o ajax nunca será disparado.
- Por algum motivo o computador desligou repentinamente, por exemplo uma queda de energia.

### API Beacon

Claro que existe a [**API Beacon**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) que é semelhante ao [`XmlHttpRequest` (vulgo Ajax)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116177/3635) **que "garante"** a entrega da requisição mesmo que a página seja descarregada (troque de página, feche a aba/janela), o que é diferente do `XmlHttpRequest` que é cancelado se a página começar a descarregar acaso ele ainda esteja em processo de envio (de 0 a 2 no valor de `readyState` geralmente).

Mas ainda que o Beacon pareça resolver muitos casos é preciso entender:

- É uma tecnologia **EXPERIMENTAL**
- Se o processo do navegador morrer abruptamente, acabar a energia e o PC desligar ou simplesmente estiver sem sinal de internet, isto nunca será entregue

Nesses casos o Beacon nunca vai entregar a requisição pro servidor.

### Alternativa ao `beforeunload`

Como eu já disse nestes dois links:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70316/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71023/3635

O recomendo é criar um *timer* (assim como o Google faz, como citei no primeiro link), ou seja *ninguém* usa `beforeunload` pois ele **não é uma pratica boa pra este propósito especifico**.

O *timer* deve ser criado no lado servidor e vai depender da linguagem que usa (no seu caso é o PHP), um exemplo que já citei no link acima seria, criar uma tabela:

```
id | login | senha | nome | lastactive
-----------------------------------------------
1  | test  | test  | João | 2015-06-24 01:00:23
-----------------------------------------------
2  | maria | maria | Maria| 2015-06-24 01:00:33
```

Supondo que eu seja o usuário de ID 1 (deve-se usar session) você teria que executar este comando a cada requisição "minha" (usando o php e o mysqli ou pdo):

```
UPDATE usuarios SET lastactive=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id=1
```

E pra verificar os usuários online:

```
define('REQUEST_TIME', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
define('TIME_ONLINE', 120);//120 = 2 minutos

function isOnline($timer) {
    return REQUEST_TIME - strtotime($timer) > TIME_ONLINE;
}

$query = 'SELECT nome, lastactive WHERE 1 ORDER by nome';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'Usuário ', $row['nome'], ' está ',
             (isOnline($row['lastactive']) ? 'online' : 'offline'), '<br>';
    }

    $result->free();
}
```

São apenas trechos de código para entender a lógica. Leia o link pra mais detalhes: [Verificar se o usuário fechou o navegador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71023/3635)

### Qual o uso de `beforeunload`

Este evento foi criado pra poder executar funções voltadas a interações com o front-end (ou seja dificilmente irá trabalhar bem com ajax devido aos fatores já citados), como por exemplo prevenir que o usuário feche acidentalmente uma página que precisa estar aberta, como um jogo online, exemplo de uso:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Gostaria mesmo de sair desta página?";
};
```

Ao tentar fechar a aba janela ou trocar de pagina irá aparecer um alert com dois botões e a sua mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Documentação:*

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Fala Guilherme, criei uma função do jeito que você colocou e fiz um primeiro teste, funcionou com sucesso. Grato pelo suporte!!!!