# Existe como cancelar o unload() ou o OnBeforeUnload()?

Tags: javascript, popup

Existe alguma maneira de cancelar o unload() ou o OnBeforeUnload()?
Algo desse tipo:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
//ação aqui
break; //cancela o fechamento da pagina sem exibir nenhum alert
}
```

Eu preciso abrir uma div (popup) quando o usuário clicar em fechar ou voltar, a ideia era colocar

```
document.getElementById('minhaDiv').style.display = 'block';
```

antes do break, mas isso não da certo porque o break não funciona e a pagina é fechada. Espero que de pra entender um pouco essa salada!

Answer (score 1):

Não é possivel cancelar e mesmo que fosse possível não seria 100% seguro, por exemplo o usuário pode matar o processo se quiser e isso não iria disparar o `onbeforeunload`.

O "máximo" que você pode fazer é perguntar ao usuário se ele quer mesmo fechar, assim:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Deseja mesmo sair?";
};
```

Se fosse possivel fazer sem o "alert" (dialogo) seria o mesmo que você controlar a máquina do usuário e realmente ninguém quer isso né?

Foi basicamente o que respondi aqui: [Rodar script js quando tentar fechar a janela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107296/3635)

Um detalhe o `onbeforeunload` não é usado pra detectar fechamento ou voltar apenas, ele é usado pra detectar qualquer descarregamento da página atual, leia mais nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80707/3635

Uma outra coisa, o `break;` não é usado pra isto, ele é usado pra loops como `for`, `while` e em `switch`, ele não para execuções de eventos apenas ciclos de loops.