# Limite de usuários em uma aplicação PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache

Ola,

Desenvolvi um sistema em php controlado por Sessions..

Verifiquei que é possível limitar o máximo de usuários online no sistema via apache(httpd.conf).

Existe alguma função(ajax, javascript, php) que eu possa limitar para 05 usuários simultâneos logados no sistema?

Answer (score 1):

> Pergunta: Verifiquei que é possível limitar o máximo de usuários online no sistema via apache(httpd.conf)

Não, isto de de limitar sessões no apache não é feito para usuários, os limites no apache seriam provavelmente pra controlar conexões, o que não garante você limitar o acesso máximo de usuários para uma site ou página, nem tem como determinar a partir disto, já que é possível manter uma sessão e existem variados tipos de uso para um conexão, como *SSE* ou usar a resposta *HTTP 100 Continue*, ou então um mesmo usuário pode abrir mais de uma conexão (para cada aba ou janela que abrir).

Mas nenhum destes é o assunto principal, se quer limitar o numero de usuários, primeiro você precisa **ensinar ao seu sistema o que é um usuário**, o usuário poderia ser checado pelo IP talvez, o que eu penso **não** ser uma boa ideia, pois um mesmo IP em uma Rede conectada em um mesmo provedor de internet (ISP) pode ser usado por vários computadores, então o que você pode fazer é usa as sessões mesmo, no entanto existe um grande PORÉM, não é possível detectar quando um usuário (que você ensinou ao seu sistema "o que é/quando é") saiu/desconectou.

A única maneira de detectar se o usuário saiu é um contador de tempo de ociosidade, ou seja se um usuário esta a 5 minutos ociosos você pode "matar" a sessão dele e determinar para os demais usuários que aquela sessão para os outros é invalida, ambos fatores, tanto quanto "matar" e quando desconsiderar para os demais irá depender exclusivamente da checagem de tempo, ou seja você não vai destruir/matar de verdade a sessão daquele usuário, é apenas uma questão de lógica.

> Talvez alguém venha lhe falar do `beforeunload` poderia ajudar, só que já lhe adianto, `beforeunload` **não** vai funcionar para detectar quando o usuário for sair, mais detalhes sobre o assunto em:
>
> - [**Rodar script js quando tentar fechar a janela**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635)
> - [**Jquery beforeunload é chamado quando clico em link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80707/3635)

Mesmo que consiga aplicar toda a lógica, ainda sim será necessário um banco de dados ou um `.txt` (o que pode ser muito mais complicado) para checar todos usuários, não precisa de fato estar autenticado, a tabela deveria ser algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id INT NOT NULL UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    session VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    lastactive TIMESTAMP
)
```

Conforme os usuários forem acessando a tabela iria ficando assim

| id | session | lastactive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22sin5grink0a22l80ej33mcj6 | 2018-06-24 01:00:23 |
| 2 | ul5c6rkacb68suu6rqmd6dubt3 | 2018-06-24 01:00:33 |

Cada session gerado na tabela foi criado no momento que a sessão foi inserida, ou seja a primeira vez que o usuário acessou, o script seria algo como:

```
<?php

session_start();
require 'conexao.php';

define('MAX_USERS', 10); //Limite de 10 usuários
define('TIME_ONLINE', time() - 120);//120 = 2 minutos

$jaEstaOnline = false;

//Verifica se você já esta na "sessão" e dentro do limite de 2 minutos para considerar se estava ocioso ou não
$queryLogado = 'SELECT id TOTAL FROM usuarios WHERE
                session = ' . session_id() . ' AND
                lastactive > FROM_UNIXTIME(' . TIME_ONLINE . ')';


//Verifica só considera as linhas (usuários) no banco dentro dos minutos
$queryConta = 'SELECT count(*) as TOTAL FROM usuarios
               WHERE lastactive > FROM_UNIXTIME(' . TIME_ONLINE . ')';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($queryLogado)) {

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $jaEstaOnline = isset($row['id']); //Verifica se existe

    $result->free();
}

//Só executa a contagem se você estiver ocioso ou se for o seu primeiro acesso
if (!$jaEstaOnline && ($result = $mysqli->query($queryConta))) {

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (!$row) {
        die('Erro na query');
    } else if ($row['TOTAL'] > MAX_USERS) {
        die('Já tem ' . MAX_USERS . ' usuários acessando');
    }

    $result->free();
}

//Verifica só considera as linhas (usuários) no banco dentro dos minutos
$query = 'SELECT count(*) as TOTAL FROM usuarios WHERE lastactive < FROM_UNIXTIME(' . TIME_ONLINE . ')';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (!$row) {
        die('Erro na query');
    } else if ($row['TOTAL'] > MAX_USERS) {
        die('Já tem ' . MAX_USERS . ' usuários acessando');
    }

    $result->free();
}

//Acaso chegar até aqui então irá atualizar o seu tempo no banco e irá determinar que você não esta ocioso, ou acaso seja o seu primeiro acesso irá te "registrar"
$query = 'REPLACE INTO my_table (session, lastactive) VALUES (session_id(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
   echo 'Você esta conectado';
} else {
   die('Você não esta conectado');
}
```

> Também seria interessante adicionar algo para apagar todas linhas com mais de uma semana por exemplo, assim diminuiria os dados desnecessário no banco

---

### Como verificar usuários online sem banco

Sim é possível fazer com um `.txt` por exemplo, mas é bem mais complicado, porque vai ter que escrever uma lógica em cima disto, mas algo assim seria o próximo do que poderia fazer:

```
<?php

session_start();

$arquivoDeUsuarios = 'caminho/para/arquivo/usuarios.txt';

define('MAX_USERS', 10); //Limite de 10 usuários
define('TIME_ONLINE', time() - 120);//120 = 2 minutos

$users = array();

if (is_file($arquivoDeUsuarios)) {
     $unserialized = unserialize(file_get_contents($arquivoDeUsuarios));

     if ($unserialized) {
         $users = $unserialized;
     }
}

$id = session_id();

//Filtra e só considera os usuários não ociosos
$users = array_filter($users, function ($tempo) {
    return $tempo >= TIME_ONLINE;
});

//Verifica se é a seu primeiro acesso, se for vazio é porque é o primeiro ou vocÊ estava ocioso
if (empty($users[$id]) && count($users) > MAX_USERS) {

     //Se o count passar do MAX_USERS é por que tem mais de 10 usuários (ou o limite que você definiu)
     die('Já tem ' . MAX_USERS . ' usuários acessando');
}

//Atualiza o tempo ou adiciona você acaso for o primeiro acesso
$online[$id] = time();

//Salva os dados
file_put_contents($arquivoDeUsuarios, serialize($users));
```

**Mas é importante notar** que usar um `.txt` pode ser algo bastante ineficiente, alguém pode conseguir gravar por cima da informação do outro antes do momento esperado, neste caso trabalhar com `LOCK` (em php [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)) junto a uma checagem recursiva ajudaria a evitar o problemas como perda de gravações, ou gravar algo por cima, no entanto isso tornaria tudo muito lento para os usuários.

Comment: Muito bom!!! Um SQLite seria uma boa com essa tua regra aplicada.

Comment: @fabianophp obrigado. Talvez Sqlite não seja tão bom com conexões concorrentes, não posso afirmar, todavia em MySql existe a Engine `memory`, que o Bacco me sugeriu, talvez eu crie uma pergunta e/ou resposta sobre ela, focado somente na utilidade do `memory`.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro, crie uma tabela com as seguintes colunas:

```
|-----------------------------------|
| IP varchar(15) | Views tinyint(1) |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Então, para cada visualização, insira o IP (se não estiver no banco de dados) ou incremente as visualizações em 1. Se views = 5, mate a página e não permita que o usuário visite.

Você pode então executar um cron todas as noites às 00:00 que exclui todos os dados na tabela (estude: truncate).