# Javascript - Mensagem antes de o usuário fechar a página (sem utilizar o onbeforeunload)

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos

Eu gostaria de saber como exibir uma mensagem antes de fechar a página, que no meu caso seria de confirmação, como o que ocorre nesse site: http://processamentodigital.com.br/

Até o momento eu só achei como fazer através do javascript com o "onbeforeunload", porém, eu gostaria de exibir uma menagem personalizada para o usuário, coisa que a função mencionada não permite.

Comment: Olá Rafa. É impossível determinar com precisão quando o usuário for fechar a janela, e também não há meio de customizar o dialogo de confirmação, leia os seguintes links: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80707/3635, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635. Para resumir, **não existe evento especifico para para capturar fechamentos**, todas tentativas de tratar isso são gambiarras usando o evento `mouseout` no `window`

Comment: Olá Guilherme! Ah sim, entendi.. De qualquer jeito, muito obrigado aí pelo retorno!