# Como pegar evento que fecha o browser?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando limpar a minha localStorage antes da janela ser fechada e nisso tentei utilizar window.unload e também window.unbeforeload. Porém, ao usar as mesmas elas limpam a localStorage se eu somente recarregar a page.

Como posso estar disparando uma função somente quando fechar o browser? Por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Não é correto usar o `localStorage` se você quer limpá-lo ao fechar o Browser.

A abordagem correta é o `sessionStorage`, que se comporta semelhante a uma sessão de uma aplicação, que, assim que encerrada, a sessão é fechada.

Veja mais em:

[Diferenças entre localStorage Vs sessionStorage?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage)

Comment: Eu queria utilizar a sessionStorage. O problema é que se o usuário abrir outra tela em outra aba não vai pegar a session. O correto seria utilizar cookie porém não tenho noção como fazer uso do mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O que o [@Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256166/3635) disse esta relativamente correto, no entanto o que o autor deseja provavelmente é "deletar o storage", quando fechar a ultima aba ou janela de um domínio especifico, então com isto o `sessionStorage` **não vai funcionar**, pois para cada aba/janela será uma sessão diferente (o que difere dos cookies).

Sobre `onbeforeunload` (e não `unbeforeload`), não é garantia de que isto vá funcionar:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
      localStorage.removeItem('chave-que-necessita-deletar');
});
```

Primeiramente `beforeunload` não é e nem nunca foi para detectar fechamento de janelas, mas sim ele detecta o descarregamento da página, seja por reload, paginação ou fechamento e não existe alternativa ou função especifica para fazer isto, como eu já respondi em:

- [**Rodar script js quando tentar fechar a janela**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113155/3635)
- [**Jquery beforeunload é chamado quando clico em link**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80707/3635)

Outra problema que pode enfrentar também é se o navegador for fechado prematuramente, o que pode fazer o `beforeunload`, por exemplo um *taskkill* ocorrer devido a outro software qualquer que solicita ao usuário reiniciar o PC (tipo um anti-vírus).

### Como resolver

E como eu já respondi outras vezes, o caminho provavelmente **mais garantido atualmente** é um "temporizador" para checar se algo já expirou, por exemplo:

- Exemplo em PHP: [**Verificar se o usuário fechou o navegador**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71023/3635)
- Comportamento do Google Analytics: [**Comportamento anômalo do Google Analytics**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70316/3635)

### Exemplo de timer em JavaScript com localStorage

Um exemplo (não testei a fundo) que deve funcionar em teste seria algo assim:

> Combinei, `setTimeout`, `Date.parse`, `Date.now`, `JSON.stringify` e `JSON.parse`

```
(function (w) {
    var l = w.localStorage, timersStorage = {};

    function realPut(key, data)
    {
        l.setItem(key, data);

        //Atualiza dados de 5 em 5 segundos para que o temporizador fique atualizado
        timersStorage[key] = setTimeout(realPut, 5000, key, data);
    }

    function isExpired(timer) {
        var expiresIn = new Date;
        expiresIn.setTime(expiresIn.getTime() + timer * 60000);

        return expiresIn < Date.now();
    }

    //Adiciona a função putStorage globalmente
    w.setStorage = function(key, value, timer) {
        //Previne conflito se acaso usar duas para uma mesma chave
        if (timersStorage[key]) {
            clearTimeout(timersStorage[key]);
        }

        realPut(key, JSON.stringify({
            expires: timer,
            data: value
        }));
    };

    //Adiciona a função getStorage globalmente
    w.getStorage = function(key, value, timer) {
        var value = l.getItem(key);

        if (!value) return;

        if (String(value).indexOf("expires") !== -1) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(value);

            if (Date.parse(parsed.expires) < Date.now()) {
                 return; //Retorna undefined se já tiver expirado
            }

            return parsed.data;
        }

        return value;
    };

    //Deleta dados que já passaram do "prazo de validade"
    var toDelete = [], toUp = [];

    for (var key in l) {
        var value = l.getItem(key);

        if (value.indexOf("expires") !== -1) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(value);

            if (isExpired(parsed.expires)) {
                toDelete.push(key);
            } else {
                toUp.push({ key: key, value: parsed.data, expires: parsed.expires });
            }
        }
    }

    //Deleta os expirados, é necessário executar fora do primeiro loop para não conflitar
    for (var i = toDelete.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        l.removeItem(toDelete[i]);
    }

    //Atualiza os que não expiraram, é necessário executar fora do primeiro loop para não conflitar
    for (var i = toUp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        w.setStorage(toUp[i].key, toUp[i].value, toUp[i].expires);
    }
})(window);
```

O uso deve ser algo como:

```
setStorage('foo', 'bar', 10); //Expira em 10 minutos (depois da ultima janela ter sido fechada)

setStorage('nome', 'joão', 1); //Expira em 1 minuto (depois da ultima janela ter sido fechada)

//Suporta dados em "json"
setStorage('dadospessoais', {"foo": "bar"}', 2); //Expira em 2 minutos (depois da ultima janela ter sido fechada)
```

Para pegar um item:

```
 console.log(getStorage('foo'));
```

Se tiver expirado retornará `undefined`